# I can open txt file in VSCODE with python, but other inputs dont work :(

Tags: python, list

I'm a begginner obviously and I'm struggling with working on a text file that I have. When I print the "dataR" I can see the whole document just fine. but when I try to work on it, it's as if the file is empty. From the "count" print, i get "0" . I have tried working on the file but it doesn't work.

#this is the code:

```
data = open('mbox-short.txt')

dataR = data.read()
print(dataR)

count = 0
for x in data:
    count += 1
    
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling read() on a _io.TextIOWrapper object, the stream will be at EOF. i.e., the entire contents of the file will have been consumed. Therefore, any subsequent attempt to iterate over that object will return nothing.

You can remedy the situation as follows:

```
with open("mbox-short.txt") as data:
    dataR = data.read()
    print(dataR)
    data.seek(0) # seek to BOF
    count = 0
    for _ in data:
        count += 1
    print(count)
```